# Apache startup fails with php_imagick extension, but loads after running php_info

Tags: php, apache, imagick

I am building a web page on a Windows PC in a localhost configuration. I have Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.2.2.  I have installed Imagemagick and the php_imagick_dyn-Q16.dll to enable the php imagick module. When I start the PC and load the web page, it fails and I get the Windows message:

```
Apache HTTP Server has encountered a problem and needs to close. . . . Tell Microsoft . . .
Error signature
szAppName : httpd.exe     szAppVer : 2.2.6.0     
szModName : php_imagick_dyn-Q16.dll     szModVer : 0.0.0.0     offset : 000172e2
These files will be included in the error report to Microsoft
C:\DOCUME~1\MICHAE~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\WER48e2.dir00\httpd.exe.mdmp
C:\DOCUME~1\MICHAE~1\LOCALS~1\Temp\WER48e2.dir00\appcompat.txt
```

When I run phpinfo.php, it shows imagick enabled.  Then when I load my web page again, everything works.  I have done this several days in a row. I thought phpinfo was a report but it seems to be some kind of trigger to start the imagick module - or something. How do I get the imagick module to happen automatically at startup, like my MySQL module does?

In the php.ini section where it says:

```
If you wish to have a module loaded automatically, , . .
```

I have:

```
extension=php_imagick_dyn-Q16.dll
```

php.ini also has a Local Variable section with things like:

```
[PHP_MYSQL]

extension=php_mysql.dll
```

do I need something similar for imagick, if so, is it:

```
[PHP_IMAGICK]

extension=php_imagick_dyn-Q16.dll
```

what does this do?

Please be specific with advice and fixes. I'm a noobie, and know very little about Apache or php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running php 5.3.10 with Apache 2.2.22 (WAMP) and this is what i have :

In php.ini :

```
extension=php_imagick_ts.dll
```

Check out this [blog](http://valokuva.org/?page_id=50)

Comment: thanks. It works even though the dll is for PHP5.3 and I'm using PHP5.2.2 The page fires up just fine.